# Where is the best documentation of Microsoft Excel Chart Biff format

Tags: excel

I am looking for the best documentation of Microsoft Excel's chart file format - 1997 - > 2003.

I am not looking for ooxml. I am not looking for the format of worksheets/workbooks. I am looking for the format of Excel **charts**.

What is the best resource on the web?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft [published these](http://www.microsoft.com/interop/docs/OfficeBinaryFormats.mspx) about a year ago in **P A I N F U L** detail.  Are you sure you don't want to just use the XML formats ? ;-)

Comment: These cover Word, Excel, Ppt and Drawing. What about Charts?

Comment: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsc.openoffice.org%2Fexcelfileformat.pdf&ei=Nk1dSv-bDJD6MNK1sK4C&usg=AFQjCNE2w4xyFSoKmvKdsa7O9TMqynYpbA&sig2=obdPpENEhWmfFz2_tgvsGQ

Chapter 7.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft also published these](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=33071438-110d-4845-9430-92775eacbee7&displaylang=en) and the one you want is [MS-OGRAPH].pdf